# AngularJS is putting forward slash / after hash tag

Tags: angularjs, hashtag, anchor-scroll

I'm trying to use AngularJS [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) with `$location.hash`. However, when I set the hash, AngularJS adds a forward slash, / after it.

For example, the url is: `http://localhost:13060/Dashboard`. When I don't include the AngularJS library, I can click the link, `#contact`, and go to `http://localhost:13060/Dashboard#contact`.

But when I include AngularJS and click the link, it goes to `http://localhost:13060/Dashboard#/contact` preventing $anchorScroll from working.

**Edit $anchorScroll not working** 
The starting URL is `http://localhost:13060/Category`.
When I add a category, it should go to `http://localhost:13060/Category#/#id` (where id is the new id) and scroll down the page to it. The URL is correctly updating but $anchorScroll is not scrolling.

```
 //jump to new category
 $location.path("");
 $location.hash(cat.ID);
 $anchorScroll();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you use html5mode, which removes the hash from angular routing, you will have 2 hashes, one for angular routing and other for anchors.

`http://localhost:13060/Dashboard#/#contact`

Assuming you had a route path set as `/profiles` and anchor was in that view the url would look like:

`http://localhost:13060/Dashboard#/profiles#contact`

Comment: I have the URL correctly formatted now, but $anchorScroll() isn't scrolling down to the page.

Comment: I'll be honest, i've never used anchorscroll. Does `$location.hash()` output what you would expect ( the second hash) ?

Comment: Yes, it updates the hash correctly (when I specify the path), but then nothing happens other than the URL browser bar reflecting the change.

Comment: I discovered the issue. I have the $anchorScroll in the result of the promise (i.e. categories.then) and I change the $scope. I was invoking the hash function before the $scope change propagated to the view and thus the hash wasn't there so it wouldn't scroll. I added a timeout to the $anchorScroll which fixed it.

Comment: @jth_92 would be nice to see a jsfiddle or something, I have the same problem but I don't see how exactly / where you have added the  

$location.path("");
 $location.hash(cat.ID);