# AngularJS Can't Use Hash to Jump to Anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got a website set up using AngularJS and I don't need to use routing, so it isn't implemented.  I want to be able to jump to a spot in the page based on an anchor, so I set up a link in my navbar that is:

```
<a href="/services#/myAnchor">Jump to anchor</a>
```

and I place farther down:

```
<a name="/myAnchor">
```

But it doesn't work, it has to be something to do with AngularJS, but since I'm not using routing I don't know what it is.  I tried using just #myAnchor with no / but Angular seems to put that in when the page loads anyway, and doesn't work anyway.

Any ideas how to get just basic in page anchors to work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll):

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
  <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>


angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
  .controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
    function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
      $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
        // set the location.hash to the id of
        // the element you wish to scroll to.
        $location.hash('bottom');

        // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591344/angularjs-is-putting-forward-slash-after-hash-tag. Looks like you have to have to hashes